# Render code example block in haml

Tags: haml

I'm trying to create an inline code block. I'm a little new to haml.

How does one create a inline code block like this:

**HTML**

```
<code>
    <article>
    <header class="article-header">Example&lt;/header>
    </article>
</code>
```

How does one do this in haml?

What i've tried:

```
%p
  %code
    &lt:article
    &lt;header class="article-header">Example</header>
    &lt;/article>
```

Comment: Format your code properly by indenting it by four spaces.

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe i missed something why should i use 4 spaces?

Comment: Indent text that you want to show up as code (in your SO question) with four spaces.

Comment: [This link will help you](http://html2haml.heroku.com/)

Comment: What have you tried? What result did it give? How did it differ from what you want/expect?

Comment: Which whitespace do you want to preserve? Newlines and spaces for purely formatting purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this article](http://chriseppstein.github.io/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/) from Chris Eppstein. I've quickly learned that haml isn't very good for inline content.

> When I say content, I mean the meat of a web page. The stuff that is
>   left after you take away the header, footer, sidebar, ads, etc. The
>   stuff the user is there to read. Don’t use Haml for adding markup to
>   your inline content.
>   - Chris Eppstein

It is ideal to pass this through via a haml plain filter or even a markdown filter:

```
  %p
   :plain
     <article>
        <header class="article-header">Example</header>
     </article>
```

Comment: IMHO, that's horrible, and just ruins the whole point of using HAML. I have a very different definition of what **content** is, and re-wrapping plain HTML/XML in HAML is not it.

Comment: What do you propose instead if i need to display for documentation purposes codeblocks for other developers ? Did you also read the article by chris eppstein the inventor of haml?

Comment: I left the comment to your original question, before the updated version explaining that you were trying to include the code block as plain text. Your original question didn't say anything about the *need to display codeblocks for documentation purposes*, and the answer your provided looked bad for the original question. Yes, I had read that article some time ago, and yes, your solution is perfectly valid. What's not cool is serial of down-voting on my questions, just because you didn't like my comments.

Comment: Also, by the way, I did not down vote your question, only the answer as it pertained to the original question.  And even if I did down vote it, your retaliation tactics look very amateur.

Answer (score 0):

```
%article
  %header.article-header Example
```

I'm not sure what white space you're trying to preserve. HAML can render this in "pretty" mode, giving you pretty formatting with indentation and spacing, or "ugly" mode, with no indentation.